# Xamarin Android runtime C# compilation

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, runtime, roslyn

I am trying to compile a simple code in C# using **Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp**.

The problem is in trying to add the reference to ***mscorlib.dll***.
As the ***CreateFromAssembly*** method of the ***MetadataReference*** class is deprecated I am trying to use the ***CreateFromFile*** method (as suggested):

```
var mscorlibAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("mscorlib.dll")).ManifestModule.Assembly;
var mscorlibref = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(mscorlibAssembly.Location);
result.Add(mscorlibref);
```

The *Location* property of the assembly returns "mscorlib.dll" and not the full path causing the error: **System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/mscorlib.dll"**

How can I load the correct MSCorLib reference to be able to use ***CSharpCompilation***?

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do?  Why do you need to load this assembly?  Are you trying to dynamically compile some C# within an Android app?

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do?  Why do you need to load this assembly?  Are you trying to dynamically compile some C# within an Android app?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do **scripting** with Xamarin Forms (Android)

Comment: Wow. Is Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp even available in Xamarin?

Comment: Yes, except for Mscorlib.dll, all other features are OK

Comment: Did you try to retrieve location from predefined type? For example `var mscorlibref = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);` or `var mscorlibref = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location), "mscorlib.dll"));` Do they return the correct location at `mscorlib.dll`?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've tried several options. The big problem is that for standard Mono assemblies the **path** of these are not displayed, but the names of the files without the complete location. Here is an image with the value of Location:[link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArVlhefUjLxntQQJ5jy3tskwH3m4)